# CSS left floats sitting on top of each other

Tags: css, html, overlap

So, I'm trying to create a div class that will display in a row and then automatically wrap to the next row when all the space is taken up.

```
.contributor_thumbnail {

    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #777;

}
```

So that when I call the code like this:

```
   <div class="contributor_thumbnail">thumb here</div>
   <div class="contributor_thumbnail">thumb here</div>
   <div class="contributor_thumbnail">thumb here</div>
   <div class="contributor_thumbnail">thumb here</div>
```

The divs will sit side by side.

Right now the divs just overlap.  Any ideas?

Comment: This just started working... Maybe I just didn't save changes before uploading

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/ydBrY/ You are probaly leaving something out that creates the problem. Post proper example either as an URL or use jsfiddle as I did.

Comment: You don't need to specify `display: block;` for divs, as they are by nature div level elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** Completely misread your question... Thought you said you **didn't** want it to be in a row. D'oh, well I'll leave this here just in case someone didn't know.

---

You're looking for the CSS `clear` property. Just add `clear: both;` to your CSS.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/zRKYM/